# Resolving a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ over $\mathbb P^n_S$ via sheafs of the form $\oplus^p\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n_S}(n)$, where $S$ is Noeth., aff.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, coherent-sheaves

I am studying Nitsure's exposé on the representability of the Hilbert functor. On p. 14, he makes the claim that
if $S$ is an ***affine*** ***Noetherian*** scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ is a ***coherent*** sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S}$, then there exist integers $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and natural numbers $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \oplus^{p}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S}}(a)\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S}}(b)\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}\longrightarrow 0
\end{equation*}
is exact. Why is that so?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^n_S$?

Comment: This is in Hartshorne II Corollary 5.18